How to create a spray paint brush in Illustrator with varying width?

Can a brush be created in Adobe Illustrator that would replicate this effect, where the beginning and end of the line segment is fatter than the middle?

A simple Stroke Profile would work. No need for a brush.

Here is a quick way to do this- with an Art Brush. Make sure you check "stretch to fit stroke length" or "stretch between guides" in the Art Brush options.

